# React/Redux - Dispatch not updating view

Tags: reactjs, redux

First small react/redux project to learn both react and redux.

The onClick event on the button element fires as I can see the value in the console (in the reducer file). However, the view is not updating.

Yes, I have looked online, and I have been stuck on this issue for a full day.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PanelContainer.js file:

```
    class PanelContainer extends React.Component {

        constructor(){
          super();
          this.state = {
            color: new Color()
          }
        }

       render(){
          return (
           <div class="container">
             <Row>
               <Cell cols={`col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3`}>
                 <Panel>
                   <PanelBody color={this.state.color.generateColor(new Gray())}>
                      <Title title={this.props.follower.count} />
                      <p>{this.props.follower.description}</p>
                      <p><button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.props.getFollower()}>Update</button></p>
                   </PanelBody>
                </Panel>
              </Cell>
            </Row>
         </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
       return {
         follower: state.followerReducer
       };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        getFollower: () => {
          dispatch(getFollower());
        },
        changeFollower: () => {
          dispatch(changeFollower());
        }
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PanelContainer);
```

FolloweReducer.js file:

```
export default (state = { follower: { count: 0, description: "Default description" } }, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "GET_FOLLOWER":
      state = { ...state, follower: action.payload };
      console.log("GET FOLLOWER", state);
      break;
    case "CHANGE_FOLLOWER":
      state = { ...state, follower: action.payload };
      console.log("CHANGE FOLLOWER", state);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
};
```

FollowerAction.js file:

```
export function getFollower() {
  return {
    type: "GET_FOLLOWER",
    payload: {
      count: 20,
      description: "New followers added this month"
    }
  }
}

export function changeFollower(){
  return {
    type: "CHANGE_FOLLOWER",
    payload: {
      count: 50,
      description: "Changed Followers!!!"
    }
  }
}
```

Store.js file:

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({
  followerReducer: followerReducer
}));

export default store;
```

App.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

import PanelContainer from "./panel/PanelContainer";
import store from "./shared/Store";

let app = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PanelContainer />
  </Provider>,
  app
);
```

Comment: it explicitly states in the redux documentation not to mutate state. http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments

Comment: @azium wait...how am I mutating state? I'm doing state = { ...state, follower: //code }...as far as I know, this is not mutating state.

Comment: You should give more code - are you initialize Provider properly ?

Comment: @Adidi added more code.

Comment: That is mutating state... read the link i posted... if you take the argument `state` and then reassign it, that's the definition of mutation. like.. `var x = 10` then later `x = 20` that's mutation

Comment: @azium so this guy is completely wrong? Look at around 6:41 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBER4Or86hE&index=18&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b

Comment: Yes that is bad practice---both by general "don't mutate stuff" standards and especially true for redux where you should never mutate / reassign the arguments in the reducer! I think that following the official documentation, such as in the link I sent you, is the best advice I can give.

Comment: @azium The funny part is, I have seen multiple sources doing this kind of approach...reassigning state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the reason you don't see any updates in your rendered view is because you're wrongly mapping your state with the props you pass to the component.
You state->props mapping function should be:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     follower: state.followerReducer.follower
   };
};
```

`state.followerReducer` is the whole state object managed by your reducer.
It's clear from this line

```
state = { ...state, follower: action.payload };
```

and from your initial state definition that you store the data you update in `state.followerReducer.follower`

With your `mapStateToProps` function you have, `{this.props.follower.count}` in the render method will be the whole reducer object (which is `{follower: {...}}`.

Comment: That was it! embarrassing...it was sticking like a sore thumb, and I didn't catch it. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, can be an easy mistake to make

Comment: when I use getDerivedStateFromProps to map state from props, props changed but state doesnt change

Answer (score 1):

(Deep solution): I suggest read this article:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-immutablejs-with-redux#why-should-i-use-an-immutable-focused-library-such-as-immutablejs

(Quick solution): I Suggest this code to resolved problem:

```
return {
  follower: Object.assign({},follower: state.followerReducer.follower}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another case your view is not updated by Redux is that you need: [ReduxPersist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

try this, and I saved my life.